# How to get Facebook Install Referrals from Facebook Ads in Flutter

Tags: flutter, facebook, install-referrer

We have a Facebook Ad for installing a mobile application. The link on the ad points to following:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailsid=com.app.example&fbclid=IwWR14PdRDl0ht5A8BygFG1h77kRuLNGnFLpgJSD7wRsGPMRqJwoz4STNyng4

After the installation when the user opens the app we want to track this FBCLID information. Is there a way to detect it in Flutter Application?

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this](https://medium.com/7span/how-to-handle-utm-params-in-flutter-android-3d19c888b600) article on medium.
It tracks the UTM params in Android and for iOS apps I have used with AppsFlyer integration.

Note: You can use AppsFlyer in Android too try to

> use - `appsflyer_sdk: ^6.5.2+2`
>
> use - `registerConversionDataCallback: true`

Your generated url should have referrer key used to track down url params in Android.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yourpackage&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dbanner%26utm_term%3Dshorts%26utm_content%3D500-off%26utm_campaign%3Dflat-50%26anid%3Dadmob
```

Comment: Yes but in case of FB ads, we are not getting URL like this. Please check the question. We are already able to track user with this kind of URL.

Comment: I have edited my answer please check again.

Comment: issue is how to get this kind of link in FB ads, because in FB ads we are only getting the posted URL.